# Sagepay - The Basket format is invalid

Tags: opayo

I am trying to submit a payment to sagepay (form version 2.2) but keep getting the following error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

> Status Detail:    3021 : The Basket format is invalid.

The basket string is:

> Nike Dri Fit Jersey Turtle Neck 2:3:£96.00:£0.00:£96.00:£288.00

regards

Answer (score 0):

v2.22 below.

You need to include the 'Number of lines of detail in the basket field:'
Note - the 'Number of lines of detail in the basket field' is not the total number of items ordered but the total number of rows of basket information.

The shopping basket contect can be passed in a single, colon-delimited field and results in looking like your example * however you need to include the 'Number of lines of detail in the basket field' so should look like **

Your example *

```
Nike Dri Fit Jersey Turtle Neck 2:3:£96.00:£0.00:£96.00:£288.00
```

Corrected example **

```
1:Nike Dri Fit Jersey Turtle Neck 2:3:£96.00:£0.00:£96.00:£288.00
```

You should send example below -

```
Number of lines of detail in the basket field: 1
Item 1 Description: Nike Dri Fit Jersey Turtle Neck 2
Quantity of item 1: 3
Unit cost item 1 without tax: £96.00
Tax applied to item 1: £0.00
Cost of Item 1 including tax: £96.00
Total cost of item 1 (Quantity x cost including tax): £288.00
```

Multiple lines can be sent as the below and notice the 4 at the start of the example shows there would be 4 lines within the basket.

```
4:Pioneer NSDV99 DVD-Surround Sound System:1:£424.68:£74.32:£499.00: £499.00:Donnie Darko Director’s Cut:3:£11.91:£2.08:£13.99:£41.97: Finding Nemo:2:£11.05:£1.94:£12.99:£25.98: Delivery:---:---:---:
---:£4.99
```

Sage Pay now run on v3.00 where the £ symbol is not confirmed in the Basket field.

```
 1:Nike Dri Fit Jersey Turtle Neck 2:3:96.00:0.00:96.00:288.00
```

If you wish to migrate/upgrade to v3.00, how to instructions is available on Sage Pay website.